# CtrlP for gvim does not find my files, max_files parameter is set

Tags: vim, ctrlp

For the life of me, I can't get CtrlP to work with my setup.

I have a verilog environment with *.sv, *.v and *.tv files. I don't have a .git, .zip etc as far as I know.

I have a my.ctrlp file in my project root directory.

Here's my config:

```
let g:ctrlp_root_markers = ['.ctrlp']
let g:ctrlp_working_path_mode = 'ra'
let g:ctrlp_match_window = ''
let g:ctrlp_max_files = ''
let g:ctrlp_max_depth=40
```

I cannot find most of my files using CtrlP.

Here's an alternate setup I tried:

```
let g:ctrlp_working_path_mode = ''
let g:ctrlp_match_window = ''
let g:ctrlp_max_files = ''
let g:ctrlp_max_depth=40
```

I tried starting `:CtrlP /project_root/` and refreshing the cache 'F5'. I can see it going through about 2200 files (not sure that's how many I have in project). But it cannot find multiple files in my /rtl/ directory. This directory has about 100 files but all I see is the same 10 or so files.

Any help will be appreciated! I really want to use CtrlP.

Also, on a separate note, is there a way to check from within gvim what the variables are for plugins? For instance, how do I know what is the ctrlp_max_files that is being currently used?

Comment: try: `let g:ctrlp_max_files=0`

Comment: I've tried that but doesn't seem to help. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: You should use the plugin's issue tracker.

Comment: I have submitted it to the plugin's issue tracker as well but I figured I'd have more people seeing the issue here.

Comment: Ok, I think I figured it out. Turns out that CtrlP does not follow symbolic links by default. Since I have a version control database, I didn't have actual files but the links to the latest version. I had to set the following option to get CtrlP working: `let g:ctrlp_follow_symlinks=1`

Answer (score 3):

Needed to add this option: (reasons in the comment above)

```
let g:ctrlp_follow_symlinks=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let g:ctrlp_match_window = 'min:4,max:10,results:100'
```